# Trying to use TPKeyboardAvoding Scroll in my App

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, tpkeyboardavoiding

I'm using `TPKeyBoardAvoidingScrollView` in my iPhone App so that the scroll view scrolls while it reaches the end of the keyboard.

By looking at the [github](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) readme, it said that I just have to drag and drop the `TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView`into my project and assign the class of a ScrollView to it. I tried it, but it doesn't behave the way it is supposed to (nothing different happens).

This is my view hierarchy, is there anything wrong with it?

- View Hierarchy

[image]

- Embedded in ScrollVIew

[image]

Comment: your scroll view is empty.

Comment: How do I add the UITextView to it through Storyboard? I know I can create it programatically, but I have too much stuff linked up to it to make major changes. If I have to then I will, but is there something I can do in Storyboard? Thanks!

Comment: @user2200321 did you find solution to this problem?

Comment: @ViruMax, sorry man I actually don't remember what I did with this, it was a while back. I'm pretty sure the accepted answer worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step 1:**

- Delete your scrollview

**Step 2:**

- Select all you components that you want to put inside a scrollview, then go to `Editor -> Embbed In -> Scroll View`. Now you will see a `UIScrolView` in your view hierarchy.

**Step 3:**

- Now select your `UIScrollView` go to the `Identity Inspector` and change the class `UIScrollView` to `TPKeyboardAvodingScrollView`

Check the [Sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9nyzmj9wjotoyjc/TPKeyboardAvoidingSample.zip)

Comment: Thanks! But this had no effect either! See my latest edit for screenshot.

Comment: Did you change the class of the `UISCrollView` to `TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView`

Comment: @user2200321 please check the sample with storyboard.

Comment: thanks much for the sample, it works great. However, I'm following an identical setup and the scrollview still refuses to move.  Could the fact that the controller is embedded in a Navigation Controller have anything to do with the problem?

Comment: @user2200321 No I dont think so. Is your scroll view at the top position or below when the keyboard appears

Comment: It actually takes up the whole page, and the keyboard just pops up over it.

Comment: @user2200321 can't understand what is causing your issue. I have worked with TPKeyboardAvoiding but never faced this issue. Just create a sample and see if its working in the sample

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. I have made textfields and embedded them in a scroll view and set the class of the Scroll View to be TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView. However, the view does not scroll up when the keyboard is hiding the bottom of the textfield. I am using storyboarding for this and it is not working.

Comment: @Siddharth did you checkout the sample project?

Comment: Scroll view is `TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView` for 'first name' field view is scrolled up, but for others (last name, email, password) view is not scrolled up. :/ any ideas? Tried to redo layout, tried setting bigger height of the view

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it seems like TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView doesnt get activated until the keyboard pops up. What worked for me were the following steps

1. Reset your simulator so that they iPhone keyboard will pop up again (it doesn't show after you use your mac keyboard)
2. Run the app again and click on a UITextView that is within the UIScrollview you created with TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView

Now it should scroll